# GlassFish 3.1, Jersey/JAX-RS logging

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

is there a way to log incoming JAX-RS requests? Or is this pretty much logging HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1):

The incoming requests are logging in the access log, like other http requests.